# Detecting an image 404 load in javascript/jquery when there is content returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run into a dilemma with jQuery's onerror handling (or more specifically the browser's javascript onerror event). I've got an image handler which loads an image from the database, and if it isn't found it returns a 404 status code but also a default not found image.

It turns out that unless the content body is empty, the browser doesn't fire the onerror event. jQuery states this is based on the response status code, but this must not be true. Anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: please post your code and the server response so that someone here can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typed a long answer but my browser chewed it ... have a look at the following article and see what happens if you bind OnError to your images *after* the DOM has loaded:

http://maisonbisson.com/post/12150/detecting-broken-images-in-javascript/

Be wary though as the method you're trying to achieve is a workaround something that's actually a valid behaviour.

Instead of returning a 404 and then a default image, why don't you simply just return the default image and an OK, if your image handler can't find the requested one ?
After all, even though it's not the specific image you need, it's still a valid, albeit default, response.

Comment: I'm guessing that he needs some indicator that the image is not valid aside from the image itself.

Comment: That's possible, but breaking the Error event isn't the way to do it! As I said, returning a valid image but saying 404 not found is logically incorrect as you did find the default image.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no choice if one is using some external service for the images (case in point, youtube, which returns default images with 404s)

Comment: Same problem here w/YouTube.  Couldn't find a front end solution, ended up sending HEAD requests to check if the images returned 404s in order of preference server side and caching the results to avoid having to do that too often.  Would be nice if the thumbnails were consistent as well, sometimes they have black borders, sometimes they don't, sometimes they're 16:9, sometimes they're 4:3, even for the same farking thumb type (e.g. maxresdefault, sddeafult, hqdefault etc).